# Intuitivity of Transition Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $b,b'$ are the bases of vector space $V$, then textbook derives transition matrix using $b'$. But, my friend says "why transition matrix uses $b'$ not $b$? I cannot understand intuitively".

What is the fundamental of derivation of matrix transition?

Comment: Do you mean the matrix for the change of basis $b\leadsto b'$? If yes, of course, *both* $b$ and $b'$ are inevitable.

Comment: The transformation matrix does use *both* $b$ and $b'$.